# iOS: My Alert message is displayed twice, but the code is only executed once

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

Here is my code that calls "displayAlert".  The problem is not only do I get an error message (wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003) but the "alert" is displayed twice!

```
if(gSiteID.globalSiteID.length == 0)  {  //  user didn't choose site
    [self displayAlert:NSLocalizedString(@"Missing Site ID", nil)  andData:NSLocalizedString(@"You must choose a site from the View Sites page",nil)];
    return;
}
```

This the code for "displayAlert":

```
- (void) displayAlert: (NSString *) title andData: (NSString *) errorMsg  {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: title
                          message: errorMsg 
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}
```

I have searched SO and Google and found nothing that is specific to my issue.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you testing this on a real device or the simulator? `wait_fences: failed to receive reply` usually means something bad happened with the debugger's connection to your device, or that you sat at a breakpoint for a really long time and it timed out. Are you sure that the code only executes once, and that nothing else could call that method? Stick breakpoints in your if statement and in your `displayAlert:andData:` method and see what happens. Run through your logic and find all the cases when that display alert method can be called and stick breakpoints on all of them.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the displayAlert method, and look at the stack trace to see where it gets called from

Comment: How do you know that the code is only run once?

Comment: I used the Debugger to trace the call... I am testing on the Simulator; and I'm positive the code is only executed once.  It's only called from two places, and the 2nd place was not executed.

Comment: wait_fences related to modal dialogs usually means that the modal dialog runloop was aborted. other than that not sure what the issue is more code might help.

Comment: Stackmonster:  I'm still getting the wait_fences problem... the other involved showing the Alert dialog twice.  I'm open to more suggestions... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you testing this on a real device or the simulator? wait_fences: failed to receive reply usually means something bad happened with the debugger's connection to your device, or that you sat at a breakpoint for a really long time and it timed out. Are you sure that the code only executes once, and that nothing else could call that method? Stick breakpoints in your if statement and in your displayAlert:andData: method and see what happens. Run through your logic and find all the cases when that display alert method can be called and stick breakpoints on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:  indeed I was calling it twice from different .cs files (do you see the egg on my face?).  Jack Lawrence please post your answer to the question, since you hit it on the head.